# MSDN like help for python programmers

Tags: python, msdn

I am new to python, coming from C# world. Is there any MSDN like help available for python programmers where I can search for classes, their methods properties etc.

Thanks,
Taimoor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pydoc.For example, you want to fine all methods in *file* class:

1. In Linux terminal, type *pydoc file*
2. Like Vim, to search a method you want, use j/k key to navigate or / key to find

Answer (score 0):

From off python documentation:

You can also use pydoc to start an HTTP server on the local machine that will serve documentation to visiting Web browsers. pydoc -p 1234 will start a HTTP server on port 1234, allowing you to browse the documentation at **http://localhost:1234/** in your preferred Web browser. pydoc -g will start the server and additionally bring up a small Tkinter-based graphical interface to help you search for documentation pages.

Now you can use pydoc via browser like msdn web pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed `python 2.7`:
you will find `pydoc` at this path:

```
/usr/share/doc/python2.7/html/index.html
```

But you cannot use the `search`.

---

If you've installed `apache2`, open this url:

```
http://localhost/doc/python2.7/html/index.html
```

You can use the `search` now.